# Теряються данные при передаче данных из Android в Arduino через Bluetooth

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth, arduino-uno

При нажатии на кнопку должны отправляться данные

**Android**

```
onClick(Viev v){
 if(myThread !=null){
    String stringSend = "1;3;4;5;2;1;";
    byte[] bytesToSend = stringSend.getBytes()
    myThread.write(bytesToSend) 
    }
}
```

**Arduino**

```
void data_parser()
{
 char block[20]; 
 int block_data;
 int ind_data,ind_block,ind_control, ind_tmp; 
 ind_data=0;
 ind_control=0;
 while(bluetooth_data[ind_data]!='\0')
 {
  ind_block=0;
  while(bluetooth_data[ind_data]!=';')
  {
   block[ind_block]=bluetooth_data[ind_data];
   ind_block++;
   ind_data++; 
  }
  block[ind_block]='\0';//zakryvayemo_block;
  block_data=0;
  for(ind_tmp=0;ind_tmp<ind_block;ind_tmp++)
  {
   block_data=block_data+(block[ind_tmp]-'0');
   if (ind_tmp<ind_block-1) block_data*=10;  
  }
  controls_array[ind_control]=block_data;
  ind_control++;
  ind_data++;//pereskakuyemo cherez symvol ';' 
 }
}
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600); 
}
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    delay(8);
    bluetooth_byte=Serial.read();
    bluetooth_msg.concat(bluetooth_byte);
  }
   if (bluetooth_msg!=""){
    bluetooth_msg.toCharArray(bluetooth_data, 20);
    Serial.println(bluetooth_msg);     
    data_parser();    
   }

}
```

В результате чего в мониторе порта вместо строки 1;3;4;5;2;1; получаю например 1;;4;5;;1; или ;3;4;5;2;; бывает что приходит нормально, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Что делает фнукция `delay(8)`?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics задержка без нее ардуино вообще принимает данные в столбец

Comment: В какой столбец?

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics что-то такое:1; новая строка 3; новая строка 4; и тд

Comment: Вы хотите прочитать строку, которую Arduino получает от хоста. Как Arduino может определить, где начало строки, а где конец строки?